# Как указать путь до определённого view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Как вернуть представление в пост запросе, с помощью ajax?

На [офф сайте microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2) написано что можно вернуть представление

`return View("Views/Home/About.cshtml");`

Но когда я отвечаю клиенту этим, то у меня приходит стандартная страничка. Как правильно прописывается абсолютный путь до файла?

У меня есть домашняя страница с которой идет ajax запрос к серверу:

```
function postSends(data){$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url: "/Method",
headers:{
    "Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Accept":"application/json; charset=utf-8"
},
data: JSON.stringify(method),//method - который пользователь выбирает на сайте
success: function (result) {
    $("#simulators").html(result);
},
error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
    console.log(xhr.statusText);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(error);
}});
```

}
Дальше я думал сделать, чтобы была фабрика и в зависимости от метода отсылала определенный .cshtml файл. А как это сделать ХЗ.

Обработчик на стороне сервера:

```
public ActionResult Method(String method)
    {IMode factMode = FactoryMode(method);
        return View(factMode.GetCSSHTMLFile());}
```

Comment: Вы хотите сделать без обрамления хедер-футер только то, что во вью написано (не используя _Layout) или у вас не видит view по указанному пути? А, кажется понял. Вам нужно в пост запросе указывать не путь ко вью (они не видны из интернета по пути), а указывать путь в формате /Controller/Action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Представления нельзя увидеть напрямую из интернета, эта папка веб-сервером не отдаётся.

Вам нужно в пост запросе указывать не путь ко вью (они не видны из интернета по пути), а указывать путь в формате /Controller/Action

Т.е. если у вас контроллер Home и ваш экшн About - указывайте url штатно как /Home/About
При этом произойдёт вызов нужного вам экшена на контроллере и покажется нужное представление.

А если при этом вам "мешает" лишний вывод из штатного layout'а страницы - то вам просто не нужно его использовать: в файле Views/Home/About.cshtml укажите в первых строчках

```
@{
    _Layout = null;
}
```

Но вообще в подобных случаях предпочтительнее возвращать не готовую разметку из представления - а данные в формате Json. Для ApiController например есть уже готовые методы - достаточно прописать `return this.Json(model);`

---

Updated Ответ на уточнённый вопрос.

> Дальше я думал сделать, чтобы была фабрика и в зависимости от метода
>   отсылала определенный .cshtml файл.

У this.View есть [несколько перегрузок](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.view?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller.View);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=aspnetcore-2.1), в том числе - которые принимают viewname - имя представления. Вы можете заготовить неколько разных вью и в экшене передавать имя и параметры.

Самый простой вариант: для представления About контроллера Home сложите несколько cshtml-файлов в папку /Views/Home/About и указывайте имя представления как About1.cshtml, About2.cshtml и т.п. без указания пути.

Альтернатива - полное имя с тильдой:

```
return View("~/Views/Home/About/About123.cshtml");
```

Для более сложных способов [ознакомьтесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/4.1.php) с тем, как происходит поиск файла представления. И вообще, можно настроить папки поиска представлений, если уж совсем кастом хочется.

Comment: А если я хочу заменять просто часть тела у тела определенным .cshtml файлом, у которого нет котроллера?? Просто если я в методе index пишу "Views/Home/About.cshtml", то отправляет куда надо. А если в ответ на post запрос, то кидает не то

Comment: @chilo5432 Без контроллера - нельзя. Максимум, что вы можете сделать - это перейти на asp.net core razor pages, там можно создать cshtml без обработчика PageModel. [Вот пример](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/29.3.php) (самый нижний), посмотрите.

Comment: @chilo5432 Но вообще чтобы избежать недоразумений - приведите в вопросе код полностью. А то кода для ajax post у вас нет вообще, а для метода Index только огрызок: вроде можно догадаться, что это экшн контроллера, но мало ли.

Comment: Надеюсь так понятнее стало.

Comment: @chilo5432 `Дальше я думал сделать, чтобы была фабрика и в зависимости от метода отсылала определенный .cshtml файл` Ах, я вас вспомнил: вы же хотели форму с разными экшн на отправку, верно? Я же говорил, что вы ходите тропами, по которым не предназначено ходить -- поэтому у вас и путь в пять раз труднее.

Comment: Да верно. Вот, а как передать правильно путь представление? То когда я пытался передать, путь меня отсылало, меня на мое домашнее представление